# Bookmarks in Visual Studio editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm looking for a plugin/addin for Visual Studio in order to bookmark a line of code.

For example bookmark line xx in file yy with mark "(1)" with keyboard shortcut alt+1 and then just pressing ctrl+1 in order to move to the line (1).

Is there anything like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Built-in:

`CTRL+K, CTRL+K`     Create a bookmark

`CTRL+K, CTRL+N`     Next Bookmark

`CTRL+K, CTRL+P`     Previous Bookmark

Comment: And is there something more sophisticated? Like the system with numbers as I described?

Answer (score 0):

A better solution to standard bookmarks...

Go to `Tools/Options/Environment/Task List` and add a new tag to record them.  I wanted to use the phrase *MARK* but this word is too common in my code, so I'm using *BOOKMARK* set as low priority.

Whenever I want to leave a bookmark I just type `//BOOKMARK: this is a bookmark`, and that's it, simple!
To view them just open the `Task List` window and sort by priority or description and scroll down.

This is hugely better than standard bookmarks because they ...

- are 'pinned' with the actual code and don't drift
- can be shared with your own multiple environments and with other developers
- are never lost if you suffer a problem with Visual Studio
- are still searchable and readable in other editors eg notepad
- you could create different tags to group different types of bookmarks together